# Return List of type implemented class

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I am having some problems refactoring some code that returns JSON data from a web service.  I've developed a base class as shown below, but this means I have to pass in the type to the GetList method.  What I really need is it to automatically pick up the type of the derived class but I can't get it to work.

```
public abstract class LocalSystemTable
{
    public abstract string TableName { get; }
    public abstract string SingularName { get; }

    public List<T> GetList<T>(string baseUri, UserCredentials userCredentials)
    {
        var response = RestClient.At(baseUri).WithContentType(ContentType.Json).For(userCredentials).Get<dynamic>();

        var result = (response.ResponseObject[TableName])[SingularName];
        bool isArray = result.GetType() == typeof(JArray);

        if (isArray)
            return result.ToObject<List<T>>();
        else
        {
            T single = result.ToObject<T>();
            return new List<T> { single };
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want to turn this:

```
GiftAidSettings settings = new GiftAidSettings();
List<GiftAidSettings> results = settings.GetList<GiftAidSettings>("some_uri", userCredentials);
```

Into this:

```
GiftAidSettings settings = new GiftAidSettings();
List<GiftAidSettings> results = settings.GetList("some_uri", userCredentials);
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: No... What you can do is make the parameter an `out parameter`, like `GetList<T>(string baseUri, UserCredentials userCredentials, out List<T> list)` or being a reference type, `GetList<T>(string baseUri, UserCredentials userCredentials, List<T> list)`

Comment: What's the point? If you just want to avoid typing `GiftAidSettings` again, use `var results = settings.GetList<GiftAidSettings>(...)`, which is no more difficult to read. You'll have to pass the type one way or another (barring the use of things like `dynamic` and explicit casts).

Comment: Thanks both, I think you're right.  I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be just to avoid typing in the type again.  I just thought there would be a simple way of doing it because it kind of felt wrong that I had to specify it again, just a chance to introduce errors.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what you want, but you can do something like this:

```
    public abstract class BaseClass<T>
        where T : BaseClass<T>, new()
    {
        public List<T> GetList(string someParameter)
        {
            return new List<T>() { new T() };
        }
    }

    public class BaseClassImplementation : BaseClass<BaseClassImplementation>
    {
        // ..............
    }
```

then:

```
    BaseClassImplementation n = new BaseClassImplementation();
    List<BaseClassImplementation> l = n.GetList("some parameter");
```